# Sort items by matching Start- and End Nodes

Tags: javascript, sorting

Let's say i have an array of randomly shuffled pieces belonging to different groups. For example:

```
let pieces = [
  {
    id: "a1",
    startNode: 18,
    endNode: 42,
  },
  {
    id: "a3",
    startNode: 16,
    endNode: 30,
  },
  {
    id: "b2",
    startNode: 48,
    endNode: 65,
  },
  {
    id: "a2",
    startNode: 42,
    endNode: 16,
  },
  {
    id: "a4",
    startNode: 30,
    endNode: 31,
  },
  {
    id: "b1",
    startNode: 23,
    endNode: 48,
  },
];
```

I want them back as two arrays in the correct order:

```
ordered = [
  [
    {
      id: "a1",
      startNode: 18,
      endNode: 42,
    },
    {
      id: "a2",
      startNode: 42,
      endNode: 16,
    },
    {
      id: "a3",
      startNode: 16,
      endNode: 30,
    },
    {
      id: "a4",
      startNode: 30,
      endNode: 31,
    },
  ],[
    {
      id: "b1",
      startNode: 23,
      endNode: 48,
    },
    {
      id: "b2",
      startNode: 48,
      endNode: 65,
    },
  ]
];
```

They are sorted by their matching start- and end nodes, so "a2" goes after "a1", because its startNode matches with "a1"s endNode. "b1" and "b2" belong to a different group, because they do not share a start- or end node with any of the "a" group. The id cannot be used for sorting, it's just for clarity here.

Any ideas on how to do that? I think it needs some sort of recursive function and I cannot quite get that into my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an iterative approach while iterating the sub results as well against the actual (outer) element.

This single element collects in an array all matching start and end nodes, whereas the other non matching nodes are filtered and later with the collecting array concatinated.

```js
var pieces = [{ id: "a1", startNode: 18, endNode: 42 }, { id: "a3", startNode: 16, endNode: 30 }, { id: "b2", startNode: 48, endNode: 65 }, { id: "a2", startNode: 42, endNode: 16 }, { id: "a4", startNode: 30, endNode: 31 }, { id: "b1", startNode: 23, endNode: 48 }],
    result = pieces.reduce(function (r, a) {
        var temp = [a];
        return r.filter(function (b) {
            if (temp[temp.length - 1].endNode === b[0].startNode) {
                temp = temp.concat(b);
                return;
            }
            if (temp[0].startNode === b[b.length - 1].endNode) {
                temp = b.concat(temp);
                return;
            }
            return true;
        }).concat([temp]);
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow Nina, that really does the trick. I've tried it with some more data too and it works like a charm. Now I need to take a very close look at what you did there with the filter function. Thank you endlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Try with simple [`Array#sort()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjry5Djnt7UAhWFrY8KHY_PCFsQFggrMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fsort&usg=AFQjCNEGi0Cab6xU1_1jrxG44Qu1jxuBXg) =>`a.id > b.id`

```js
let pieces = [ { id: "a1", startNode: 18, endNode: 42, }, { id: "a3", startNode: 16, endNode: 30, }, { id: "b2", startNode: 48, endNode: 65, }, { id: "a2", startNode: 42, endNode: 16, }, { id: "a4", startNode: 30, endNode: 31, }, { id: "b1", startNode: 23, endNode: 48, }, ];

console.log(pieces.sort((a,b)=> a.id > b.id))
```

Unsupported arrow function `=>` use with **ES5**

```
   console.log(
    pieces.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.id > b.id})
    )
```

Comment: even though that works for the test case I think the sort should be startNode == previous endNode

Comment: Sorry, but the id and node values are actually some arbitrary 9-digit number sequence. I modified them here for readability. They cannot be used for sorting, only the node values.